# python 'for key in' - how to fix 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to install (python setup.py install) some python package from github (https://github.com/danielfullmer/nzbfs) but getting

```
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/nzbfs/fs.py', 135, 15, "            for key in ('st_atime', 'st_ctime', 'st_gid', 'st_mode', 'st_mtime', 'st_nlink', 'st_size', 'st_uid'):\n"))
```

whats wrong? tried python2.6 + 3.1 on debian but always getting stuck on that `for key ..` line

```
def getattr(self, path, fh=None):
    st = os.lstat(self.db_root + path)

    d = {
        key: getattr(st, key)
        for key in ('st_atime', 'st_ctime', 'st_gid', 'st_mode',
                    'st_mtime', 'st_nlink', 'st_size', 'st_uid')
    }

    if stat.S_ISREG(st.st_mode):
        nzf_size = get_nzf_attr(self.db_root + path, 'size')
        if nzf_size is not None:
            d['st_size'] = nzf_size
        nzf_mtime = get_nzf_attr(self.db_root + path, 'mtime')
        if nzf_mtime is not None:
            d['st_mtime'] = nzf_mtime
    d['st_blocks'] = d['st_size'] / 512

    return d
```

Comment: This is a dictionary comprehension which is only valid in python 2.7 and up, so using 2.6 won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line that gives you a syntax error is called a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays); these were added to the language in Python 2.7 and 3.

This module is *not* Python 3 ready; it uses the `ConfigParser` module for example, which has been renamed `configparser` in Python 3. You'll have to stick with Python 2.7.

If that is a showstopper for you, you'll have to [raise an issue](https://github.com/danielfullmer/nzbfs/issues) with the developer, asking for Python 2.6 compatibility (not that hard to achieve).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the dict comprehension to this

```
d = dict(
        (key, getattr(st, key))
        for key in ('st_atime', 'st_ctime', 'st_gid', 'st_mode',
                    'st_mtime', 'st_nlink', 'st_size', 'st_uid')
    )
```

if you need it to work in 2.6

Comment: I shied away from telling the OP how to fix *this particular instance*; the codebase is large enough, it can easily hide more Python 2.7-only syntax that'll need fixing too.